# Как вернуть FSM к предыдущему шагу для перезаписи state

Tags: telegram, aiogram

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно вернуть машину состояний на шаг назад?
Есть бот, который по порядку собирает ответы от пользователя, каждый ответ кладет в заранее прописанные state'ы и по итогу кладет через sqlite3 в db.
На одном из шагов предполагается принятие целочисленного значения от пользователя. Проверим `message.text` на `int/str` и в случае `==int` пишем в state и отправляем на `next`, но как вернуться если значение `==str` и повторить вопрос для данного state еще раз не понимаю. Пробовал `while`, бот бесконечно спамил сообщениями)
Может есть какой-то оператор вместо `next`, в документации aiogram покопался - не нашел ничего. Ниже кусок где идет по порядку запрос данных от пользователя

```
async def cm_start(message : types.Message):
    try:
        if int(staff.users[f'{message.from_user.id}']['shop_id']) > 0:
            await FSMAdmin.sales_now.set()
            await message.reply('Введи текущие продажи')
    except KeyError as e:
        await message.reply('Вы не зарегистрированы, обратитесь к вашему DM')        

#Ловим ответ от пользователя
async def sales_now(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['sales_now'] = message.text
    await FSMAdmin.next()
    await message.reply("Введи историю на этот час")

#Ловим второй ответ
async def load_sales_now_ly(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['sales_now_ly'] = message.text
    await FSMAdmin.next()
    await message.reply("Введи средний чек в деньгах")
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

Чтобы требовать от пользователя выполнения нашего условия, нужно при переходе к функции, которая отвечает за запись следующего `state` сначала проверить `message.text` на наше условие, и если введенный пользователем текст удовлетворяет условиям, то пишем данные из `message.text` в `data` и отправляем машину в `next`.

Если же условие не выполнено, то отправляем сообщение пользователю с просьбой ввести что нужно (в зависимости от ваших необходимостей).
Машина при этом будет находиться в одном `state` и ждать данные для него, не сбрасывая то, что ввели ранее. Пример кода ниже:

```
#Ловим шестой ответ
async def load_targets(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['targets'] = message.text
    await FSMAdmin.next()
    await message.reply("Введи историю на день")

#Ловим седьмой ответ
async def load_history(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text == '666':
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['history'] = message.text
            await FSMAdmin.next()
            await message.reply("Введи выручку week to now")
    else:
        await message.reply("Вы ввели некорректное значение, повторите ввод")
```